# Images database schema

Tags: database, database-design

I'm trying to store user profile pictures, uploaded images in statuses, etc. on my site. When the user uploads a profile picture, there should be 3 types of the same image (Original image, medium sized, small sized). This is stored in the filesystem. A user can upload a maximum of 2 pictures in their statuses and each of these images follow the same types (original, medium, and small). The reason why I'm making different thumbnails of the same image is to serve those images depending on which screen display the user is accessing the site.

That being said, what is the best way to store these image's file paths in my database? What kind of schema makes the best sense, or if there is another better way I can serve these images, what is the best approach? For the profile image table, I was thinking something like this:

```
id  user_id  size  img
1   2        S     /img/s/avatars/ex.jpg
2   2        M     /img/m/avatars/ex.jpg
3   2        L     /img/l/avatars/ex.jpg
```

Does this look like a good approach?

Comment: Save only one image in the db and add methods to fetch the s, m, l versions of the file. There's no real need to add extra rows to your db.

Comment: @dirkgroten Are you saying to add a function that will grab the path of the original image for example: `/path/to/original/image.png' and change original to medium for example so it'll be '/path/to/medium/image.png`?

Comment: there's a few ways you could do it, but yes, constructing the path, then checking if the image already exists if not, create it and save it and return the path. alternatively, you could save a list of the image versions created as a JSONField for the image.

Comment: @dirkgroten hmm why would I check if the image already exists? For example, user uploads a profile pic, there will always be 3 versions of that profile pic. The original image path will be stored in the database, we take that image path and use functions for smaller sized screens

Comment: ah ok, if you create the 3 versions immediately when the image is uploaded then you don't need to check. I create them only when requested the first time.

Comment: @dirkgroten but if you create them upon request, how do you check that same image path again? How do you know the name of the image?

Comment: as you said, it's based on the original path. if the original path is /path/to/original/filename.jpg then the others are /path/to/original/medium/filename.jpg etc... if the file doesn't exist when I call the method `image.medium()` then I first create it. The method returns the path.

Comment: @dirkgroten I see, but let's say inside the medium avatars, there's already an image with that name. Upon request, how do you solve the problem of duplicate image names?

Comment: but that can't happen because then I would have two originals with the same name. All the scaled versions have the same name as the original image, except in a different folder. Since django takes care of renaming the original if there's a conflict, I just use that name for the scaled images.

Comment: @dirkgroten Do you use an SEO friendly name or just a random image name Django picks?

Comment: User uploaded images usually don’t have SEO friendly names. But anyway Django doesn’t change the name it only appends a hash if necessary to deduplicate. That works with SEO.

Comment: Again the alternative could be saving a dictionary of the scales images as JSON in your image row in the db. That way you have full control over paths and names.

Comment: @dirkgroten You're right, user uploaded images don't have seo friendly names...I like your idea of the functions better, but in your case what is the purpose of only creating those images upon request. Are there any benefits?

Comment: I like just-in-time creation in general because it allows to save resources that might never get used.